# Вызов процедуры/функции delphi из ассемблера

Tags: winapi, delphi, ассемблер

Всем привет)

Осваиваю асм в дельфях (вроде BASM). Осилил основные операции, работу с int/char, указателями. Запарываюсь на вызове функций. Кто в курсе, подскажите, что вставить в код и, если не сложно, объясните, что там важно/нужно учитывать.

Моя наработка, ожидаемый результат - массив заполнен случайными int'ами.

```
procedure fillInt32(p: pointer; sz, max: integer); register;
  asm    
    mov ebx, max    {
                      заглушка, так процедура работает 
                      вместо нее ожидается что-то вроде "mov ebx, random(max)"
                      после @lb, но это, естественно, не работает) 
                    }
    @lb:
    mov dword ptr [eax], ebx // присваиваем max элементу
    add eax, 4               // сдвигаем указатель на 4 байта
    sub sz, 1                // уменьшаем длину
    cmp sz, 0                // если длина != 0
    jnz @lb                  // в начало цикла, иначе выходим
  end;
```

Вызов:

```
const
  arrSz: 16;
type
  int32: longint;
  TArr: array[0..(arrSz-1)] of int32;
  PArr: ^TArr;
var
  aint32: PArr;

begin
  aint32 := allocMem(arrSz * sizeOf(Int32));
  fillInt32(aint32, arrSz, 20);
  { ... }
end.
```

Гуглил, искал в 2 книгах, там только методы. Я и этот механизм не совсем понимаю, но там хоть примеры довольно прозрачные есть, а вот вызов обычных функций из дельфей/винапи не нашел. На крайний случай нашел реализацию ГПСЧ на basm, но цель сейчас образовательная.

ЗЫ: Delphi 7, win32

**UPDATE [ решено ]** я так понял, у рандома что-то не так с возвращаемым значением. Конечный код:

```
function MRand(max: int32): int32;
begin
  Result:= 1+random(max);
end;

procedure fillInt32(p: pointer; sz, max: int32);
  asm
    mov eax, p
    mov ebx, sz
    mov ecx, max
    @lb:
    push eax
    mov eax, ecx
    call MRand
    mov edx, eax
    pop eax
    mov dword ptr [eax], edx
    add eax, 4
    sub ebx, 1
    jnz @lb
  end;
```

**И еще небольшой апдейт**

На самом деле:

```
call System.@RandInt { то есть, call Модуль.@Символ }
```

Вот такие пироги) Еще раз спасибо всем за участие.

Comment: А что не так?  
По умолчанию для Delphi соглашение передачи параметров через регистры для подпрограмм объявленных `register;`, если количество параметров не больше 3-хю В остальном случаи через стек.  
PS: BASM это Borland ASM.

Comment: На вопрос не отвечу - не знаком со спецификой дельфи, скажу про ассемблер:

    cmp sz, 0                // если длина != 0

эта проверка лишняя, т.к. команда **sub** сама если надо модифицирует **zf**.

Comment: Что не так... Не работает оно) Если MOV EBX, random, в ebx попадает фиксированное число. CALL random стабильно выдает ошибку. INVOKE неизвестен (на всякий случай тестил). Про борланд я ниже написал, да)

Comment: К сожалению не знаю, как в Дельфи. В Си можно посмотреть ассемблерный код, создаваемый компилятором (gcc -S t.c) будет в t.s, а потом по аналогии вызвать функцию у себя.

Наверное в Дельфи тоже можно (тут был вопрос в котором был ассемблерный код из Паскаля).

Comment: @dword благодарю)

Comment: invoke это макрос, который при компиляции превращается в несколько push и call. В инлайн-ассемблере такого макроса скорее всего нет.

Comment: @Sh4dow, p не записывается в eax, а потом обращение идет, как будто он там лежит. А вообще я предполагал что в делфи (как и в других языках программирования) параметры в процедуры/функции по-умолчанию передаются через стек, а не через регистры.

Comment: @insolor еще раз спс и +10, выбил все аномалии

вообще int32-аргументы передаются в регистрах, но у меня какого-то хрена max оказывался в ebx, ecx и edx одновременно. В общем, насильно зсунул их в регистры, теперь все как надо работает)

Comment: [Википедия: соглашения вызова, fastcall](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Соглашения_вызова#fastcall):

> Fastcall Borland применяется по умолчанию в Delphi.

Вот теперь все стало на свои места:)

Comment: Что-то не нашел его компилятора Delphi ключа для генерации ассемблерного листинга. В ответе для вопроса "какой код будет работать быстрее?" я генерировал листинг через компилятор Free Pascal с помощью ключа -Amasm. В крайнем случае можно загнать объектный файл в дизассемблер, например фриварную версию IDA.

Comment: @insolor И снова благодарность)

Теперь юзаю модификатор **pascal;**, тогда вызов идут через стек. Че-то у меня нет настроения угадывать, где аргумент.

Листинг можно просмотреть (по крайней мере, я только это нашел) таким неочевидным способом: ставим breakpoint перед интересующей строчкой, жмем F9, жмем Ctrl+Alt+C - появляется окно CPU со всеми бывшими и будущими командами. Не совсем то, но юзабельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Random ( LimitPlusOne : Integer ) : Integer;
```

А сколько занимает в delphi `Integer`? 4 байта, должно работать.

Comment: Именно этот комментарий помог) Сделал свой аналог random, вызвалось.

Answer (score 1):

Ни про какой BASM раньше не слышал. Здесь я так понимаю просто используется инлайн-ассемблер.

По поводу вопроса, если имеется в виду вызов фуникции random из ассемблерного кода, то примерно так (будем считать что в ebx лежит значение max):

```
push ebx
call random
```

В eax должно оказаться полученное случайное число.

**UPD.** У меня Delphi 2010, вот это успешно компилируется, насколько правильно работает нужно еще проверять.

```
procedure fillInt32(p: pointer; sz, max: integer); register;
  asm
    mov ebx, max
    mov edi, p
    @lb:
    push ebx
    call random
    mov dword ptr [edi], eax // присваиваем случайное число элементу
    add edi, 4               // сдвигаем указатель на 4 байта
    sub sz, 1                // уменьшаем длину
    cmp sz, 0                // если длина != 0
    jnz @lb                  // в начало цикла, иначе выходим
  end;
```

Comment: .

    46: push ebx
    47: call random

    [Error] testasm.dpr(47): Invalid combination of opcode and operands

да, basm = borland assembler

Comment: @ildar Стандартно (в delphi7) - integer == longint(4 байта), я объявил инт32 на всякий случай, если придется под х64 портировать. 

А про функцию не понял. Переобъявить ее или?

Comment: .
    
    
    mov edi, pointer

Вот это вряд ли правильно отработает, но все равно спасибо)

Comment: Тфу ты, mov edi,p

В оригинале p не записывается в eax, а потом обращение идет, как будто он там лежит.